# Windows 7 share not accessible from OSX - how to debug

Tags: windows-7, macos, logging

I have a Win7 machine and a shared directory on that. Users log on via a domain. This all works fine from another Windows client, but not from Macs at all (Lion or Mountain Lion). The OSX error message is rather general, something like 'could not connect to server'.
Google yields a plethora of similar questions, all with various suggested solutions. The only one I tried is looking at the authentication options on the Server, which were set as suggested.

My actual question is: Where are the logs on Windows and OSX which I should look at to find out what the actual problem is? There must be more detailed error messages somewhere, I'm not a fan of trying random solutions from forums that may or may not be related to the actual problem.